# Grails Field Plugin: Select tag for one-to-many relationships

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 2.2.3 and Fields plugin 1.3. 
I want to customize fields to manage one-to-many relationships using select tag.

In `views/_fields/oneToMany/_input.gsp` I have:

```
<g:select name="${property}.id" from="${type.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${value}" class="form-control one-to-many" noSelection="['null': "${label}"]" />
```

But `type` is a set, so I can't use `list` function.

How can I retrieve target domain class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you use a Map to declare the relationship, for example:

```
static hasMany = [ books: Book ]
```

You can get the list of the referenced domain, which is the key from the `hasMany` property of the *bean*, so the `from` attribute should change to

```
from="${bean.hasMany[property].list()}"
```

Alternatively you can pass the list to the `_input.gsp` template prefixing the variable name with `input-`,  e.g.

```
<f:field property="books" input-domainList="${bookInstaceList}" />
```

In the `_input.gsp` template you can use the variable as follows:

```
from="${domainList}"
```

or mixing both methods:

```
from"${domainList ?: bean.hasMany[property].list()}"
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm! :)

Comment: the "input-..." like params recently changed to "widget-..."

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution for the problem, this code work fine with one to many and one to one

```
<div class="input-group">
  <g:select name="${persistentProperty.toString().contains('one-to-many')?property:property+'.id'}" value="${value?.id}" required="${required}"
    noSelection="${['null':'Escriba...']}" class="select2 col-md-6"
    multiple="${persistentProperty.toString().contains('one-to-many')?true:false}" from="${grailsApplication.getDomainClass(persistentProperty.properties['associatedEntity'].toString()).clazz.list()}"
    optionKey="id"></g:select>
</div>
```

This solution can be helpful. I found in the documentacion of Fields Plugin, the persistentProperty is a class type DomainProperty but their methods doesn't works and I found the correct class is org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.MappingFactory

Answer (score 0):

you can use .toArray() method on your Set instead of .list().

ale

Comment: Thank you but Set hasn't toArray function. And I can't use also toList: in create forms the set is empty. I have to use the target domain controller list function.

Comment: As you can see in [java 6 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), Set has a .toArray() method. However when using the Model-View-Controller pattern, you don't want your view to know anything about controllers. The controller's job is to give the model to the view. In create action of your controller you can load the list and paste to view as a params.

Comment: You're right: toArray exists, but I can't execute on a null object (when I create a new object).
I want to know only controller name: `<controller>.list()` is also how Grails scaffolding manage select fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to identify the Element of your collection

```
def className = bean.hasMany[property].properties.typeName
```

See my "views/_fields/oneToMany/_input.gsp" implementation:

```
<%@ page defaultCodec="html" %>
<%
    def className = bean.hasMany[property].properties.typeName
    def simpleName = Class.forName(className).simpleName
    def beanSimpleName = bean.class.simpleName
    def createUri = "/${simpleName.toLowerCase()}/create?${beanSimpleName.toLowerCase()}.id=${bean.id}"
%>

<a id="add${simpleName}" name="add${simpleName}" href="${createLink(uri: "${createUri}")}">
        Add ${simpleName}
</a>
<ul>
    <g:each var="item" in="${value}">
        <li>
            <a href="${createLink(uri: "/${simpleName.toLowerCase()}/show/${item.id}")}">${item}</a>
        </li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```